# WebFlux issue when creating a global publisher subscription

Tags: spring-webflux

I have written to the publisher and it works if they subscribe to it every time. The problem arises when I try to make it global so that all subscribers receive the same messages.
Here is my code :

```
public class MyPublisherDemo { 

    private final ArrayBlockingQueue<SavedEvent> myBlockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100, true);

    private final Flux<SavedEvent> fx = Flux.create(event -> {
        try{
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                if(myBlockingQueue.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("back");
                    break;
                }
                event.next(myBlockingQueue.poll());
                System.out.println("next");
            }
            event.complete();
            System.out.println("complete");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            event.error(new RuntimeException(e));
        }
    });


    private final ConnectableFlux<SavedEvent> cf = fx.publish();

    public Flux<String> getFluxTest(SavedEvent savedEvent){

        myBlockingQueue.add(savedEvent);
        cf.connect();
        return cf.map(SavedEvent::getOccurredEvent);
    }

    public int getQueueSize(){
        return myBlockingQueue.size();
    }
}
```

And I wrote the following test to check:

```
@Test
    public void test5(){
        try {
            MyPublisherDemo myPublisherDemo = new MyPublisherDemo();
            Runnable task = () -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Run");
                myPublisherDemo.getFluxTest(new SavedEvent().builder()
                                .id(1L)
                                .occurredEvent("(" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ")" + " Coffee Machine start")
                                .eventTime(LocalDateTime.now())
                                .fillTheWaterTank(1000)
                                .fillCoffeeTank(1000)
                                .build())
                        .subscribe(
                                event -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + event),
                                System.out::println,
                                () -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " end")
                        );
            };
            Thread th1 = new Thread(task, "thread-1");
            th1.start();

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            Thread th2 = new Thread(task, "thread-2");
            th2.start();


            Thread.sleep(20000);
            System.out.println("Queue size = " + myPublisherDemo.getQueueSize());
            System.out.println("Basic thread run. End program.");

        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```

The structure of SavedEvent I think is clear from builder().
The point of the publisher is to wait for the event for 5 seconds if the current event is still being processed.
The version I used before:

```
    private final ArrayBlockingQueue<SavedEvent> myBlockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100, true);
    private final AtomicInteger counterRequest = new AtomicInteger(100);

    private final Flux<SavedEvent> fx = Flux.fromIterable(myBlockingQueue)
            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(7))
            .map(data ->{
                myBlockingQueue.poll();
                counterRequest.decrementAndGet();
                return data;
            })
            .repeat(counterRequest.get());

    private final ConnectableFlux<SavedEvent> cf = fx.publish();
```

Problem when working with two subscribers they don't receive all messages.

```
thread-1 Run
thread-2 Run
thread-1 (thread-1) Coffee Machine start
next
thread-1 (thread-2) Coffee Machine start
next
back
thread-1 end
complete
Queue size = 0
Basic thread run. End program.
```

The result I'm expecting:

```
thread-1 Run
thread-2 Run
thread-1 (thread-1) Coffee Machine start
thread-2 (thread-1) Coffee Machine start
next
thread-2 (thread-2) Coffee Machine start
thread-1 (thread-2) Coffee Machine start
next
back
thread-1 end
complete
back
thread-2 end
complete
Queue size = 0
Basic thread run. End program.
```

If the error is in how I'm trying to implement the publisher, please write how it should be done correctly. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While experimenting with RxJava I found a solution on the net:

```
let myObservable = Observable.just(1).publish()

print("Subscribing")
myObservable.subscribe(onNext: {
    print("first = \($0)")
})

myObservable.subscribe(onNext: {
    print("second = \($0)")
})

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    print("Calling connect after 3 seconds")
    myObservable.connect()
}
```

It's not obvious, but for the first subscriber, you first need to have a subscription to the publisher and then you need to start the publisher.I did not understand why this is so. It works.

```
public class MyPublisherDemo { 

    private final ArrayBlockingQueue<SavedEvent> myBlockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100, true);
    private final AtomicBoolean connectFlag = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private final ConnectableFlux<String> myEventGenerator = Flux.create(event ->{
        try{
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                if(myBlockingQueue.isEmpty()){
                    break;
                }
                event.next(myBlockingQueue.poll());
            }
            connectFlag.getAndSet(false);
            event.complete();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            event.error(new RuntimeException(e));
        }
    }).map(event -> {
        SavedEvent se = (SavedEvent) event;
        return se.getOccurredEvent();
    }).publish();

    public Flux<String> getFluxTest(SavedEvent savedEvent){

        myBlockingQueue.add(savedEvent);
        delayedStart();
        return myEventGenerator;
    }

    public int getQueueSize(){
        return myBlockingQueue.size();
    }

    private void delayedStart(){
        if (!connectFlag.getAndSet(true)) {
            Runnable task = () -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    myEventGenerator.connect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
            };
            Thread th1 = new Thread(task);
            th1.start();
        }
    }
}
```